# Auto Increment when importing SQL file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a script that should generate an SQL file to be imported to WordPress databases. But the generated script doesn't work when it's imported (with PHPMyAdmin). It says that there is a duplicated key of "0" for a primary field. However, when I copy and paste the content of the SQL file, everything works fine and the data is inserted correctly. I just made a test with random values for the ID field, and it works fine when I import the file. So it seems like the "auto-increment" property is somehow not taken into account when I import the script. Any idea what is causing that?

Here are a few examples :

- The queries normally generated, which generate the error mentioned above :

  ```
  INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES('','',NOW(),NOW(),'','Product 1','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','product','',0,479), ('','',NOW(),NOW(),'','Product 2','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','product','',0,48),  ('','',NOW(),NOW(),'','Product 3','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','product','',0,517);
  ```
- The queries with a random value in the ID field :

  ```
   INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES('1599','',NOW(),NOW(),'','Product 1','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','product','',0,479), ('1021','',NOW(),NOW(),'','Product 2','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','product','',0,489), ('4599','',NOW(),NOW(),'','Product 3','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','product','',0,517);
  ```

The last example works fine. The first one only works when I copy and paste the code in PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a script which list columns and in values skips the ID column, but provides values for all other ones, that will force the DB engine to generate those IDs. I think what is happening to you is that since the value is provided, but not a number it get s converted to 0 and then next one gets also converted to 0 violating PK constraint. Below is how I typically populate dummy data into the DB (ID field would be first listed, but is skipped)

```
INSERT INTO user_data
(`user_id`,`data_code`,`data_type`,`language`,`user_agent`,`user_ip`,`created_date`,`created_date_ts`) VALUES (185143,'FF','w','fr','user agent','0.0.0.0','2014-08-06 16:59:56',1407344396);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Do you mean that "185143" could be any other value, even 0 or a blank field?

Comment: Actually in my case 185143 is an actual use id, the table has a one more column before user_id called id and that column is set to auto_increment. That's the column I don't provide a value for and databse auto-generates that for me.

Comment: i allways insert the value NULL for an auto incremente column. Like this i can quickly see whether it's auto increment or not